# Firefox ignores CSS animations on SVG patterns, is it normal ?

Tags: svg

I have an SVG pattern displayed inside a clip-path that I want to animate with CSS. Firefox does not play the animation but Chrome does. If I change the `<pattern>` tag to a `<g>` tag the animation is played in both.

I know I can animate the clip-path instead but the pattern is made of several paths with different animations, so I see no other solution.

See here : https://jsfiddle.net/0xyu66mf/1/

Comment: I think we already have a bug in bugzilla covering this (although I think the usecase there was masks).

Comment: Thank you indeed there is a lot more material about it when searching with "mask". Well that's really too bad !

Comment: Feel free to download the souce and fix it. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1118710

Comment: Yes but might be too soon for me, still figuring out how SVG works !